# Android - How to create Profile view like Google Inbox?

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I want to create a profile view like the Google Inbox one as shown in the link image below, but I didn't find anything over the internet.

[Google Inbox profile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK8Nn.png)

I think that this is a Fragment, but I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

A very nice example how to create an interface similar to the one employed by Google's Android apps (Gmail, Youtube, etc.) is [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer).

From structure perspective, this example contains one main activity and several fragments. Basically each fragment represents a view that is called once you click a menu item.